# Unable to get a VBA created Schedluled Task to work when PC is sleeping

Tags: excel, vba, scheduled-tasks

I have created a process that generates a windows scheduled task using VBA.  The task launches an excel workbook at a specified date/time and executes a VBA macro it contains.  The task is a onetime execution task.  When the macro finishes it leaves the workbook opened.  The process works, but only when the PC is not sleeping at the specified date/time.  My environment is Windows 11 and Office 365.  The task history shows that the task does execute, but the excel workbook is never opened if the PC is sleeping.
I have set the parameter for **wakeToRun** as **true**.  I have tried the example shown here, which is configured to schedule the task to logon as type Interactive Token **(3)**.

I have also tried as type Password (1).  When using type 1 with my PC logon/password specified, the task times out and the workbook is not opened even if the PC is not sleeping. This is the line that registers the task:

```
Call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Book1", taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Paste the example code into a workbook and save as Book1.  Define two named ranges, **StartDt** and **StartTm**, each referencing a separate cell, which will hold the execution start date/time.

```
Sub CreateVBSFile()
    ' only need to do this once
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileStream As TextStream
    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(Environ("TEMP") & "\MyTestRun.vbs")
    Dim sS As String
    ' use book1.xlsm as name for the workbook
      sS = "ExcelFilePath = """ & ThisWorkbook.FullName & """"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
      sS = "MacroPath = ""Module1.testHarness"""
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
      sS = "Set ExcelApp = CreateObject(""Excel.Application"")"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
      sS = "ExcelApp.Visible = True"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
      sS = "ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
      sS = "Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
      sS = "ExcelApp.Run MacroPath"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
    sS = "wb.Save"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
    sS = "ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True"
    fileStream.WriteLine sS
    
    fileStream.Close
    Set fileStream = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
Sub createTheSchedule()
        
    Cells(3, 3) = ""
    'value the start time to be 10 minutes from now, or what ever time you need to test when sleeping
    Range("StartTm") = Format(DateAdd("s", 600, Now), "hh:mm ampm")
    Range("StartDt") = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    Const TriggerTypeTime = 1
    Const ActionTypeExec = 0
    Dim service As Object
    Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.service")
    Call service.Connect
'********************************************************
' Get a folder to create a task definition in.
    Dim rootFolder
    Set rootFolder = service.GetFolder("\")
    Dim taskDefinition
    Set taskDefinition = service.NewTask(0)
' creating the RegistrationInfo object.
    Dim regInfo
    Set refInfo = taskDefinition.RegistrationInfo
    refInfo.Author = "Administrator"
    
' creating a TaskSettings object.
    Dim settings
    Set settings = taskDefinition.settings
    settings.Enabled = True
    settings.WakeToRun = True
    settings.StartWhenAvailable = True
    settings.Hidden = False
    settings.idlesettings.RestartOnIdle = True
    settings.idlesettings.StopOnIdleEnd = False
' Create a time-based trigger.
    Dim triggers, trigger
    Set triggers = taskDefinition.triggers
    Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeTime)
    Dim startTime
    Dim time
    ' set your start date time using values in the workbook
    time = CDate(Range("StartDt")) + CDate(Range("StartTm"))
    startTime = XmlTime(time)
    trigger.StartBoundary = startTime
    trigger.ExecutionTimeLimit = "PT5M"    'Five minutes
    trigger.ID = "timeTriggerID"
    trigger.Enabled = True
' Add an action to the task to run the workbook
    Dim Action
    Set Action = taskDefinition.Actions.Create(ActionTypeExec)
    Action.Path = Environ("TEMP") & "\MyTestRun.vbs"
' Register (create) the task.
    Call rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Book1", taskDefinition, 6, , , 3)
        
End Sub
Function XmlTime(t)
    Dim cSecond, cMinute, CHour, cDay, cMonth, cYear
    Dim tTime, tDate

    cSecond = "00"
    cMinute = "0" & Minute(t)
    CHour = "0" & Hour(t)
    cDay = "0" & Day(t)
    cMonth = "0" & Month(t)
    cYear = Year(t)

    tTime = Right(CHour, 2) & ":" & Right(cMinute, 2) & _
        ":" & Right(cSecond, 2)
    tDate = cYear & "-" & Right(cMonth, 2) & "-" & Right(cDay, 2)
    XmlTime = tDate & "T" & tTime
End Function
Sub testHarness()
    Cells(3, 3) = "This ran successfully at " & Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss ampm")
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
I found a post explaining that windows 2008 has an issue with creating a scheduled task that has a program/script value which exceeds 30 characters, with instructions to handle that.  I then noticed that the scheduled task created by the VBA script set the task up to be configured for **windows server 2008**.  I manually modified that property using the Task Scheduler editor to be **Windows 10**

[image]

[image]

IT now will run when the PC is sleeping as expected.  However I cannot find any documentation on how to set that property via VBA, and have only been able to modify the task after it is created.  Anyone know how to set that property?

Comment: Inspecting the Scheduled Task object in VBA for either **Configuration for:** setting has every property valued the same, with one exception.  Looking at the XML property the **Task Version** is either "1.2" or "1.4".  The XML is read only and therefore cannot be modified via VBA.